# About converging sequence of norm-one elements of $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I got stuck in this question for days, so any help/hint is appreciated.

Assume that $T$ is the unit ball in $\ell^2$ and $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset T$ and that $(x_n(i))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y(i)$ for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$, show that if $\Vert y \Vert_2=1$; then $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y$ in norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write:
$$\tag {1}
\|x_n-y\|^2=\langle x_n-y,x_n-y\rangle = \|x_n\|^2+1-2\text{Re}\,\langle x_n,y\rangle
$$
Fix $\varepsilon > 0  $. Then there exists  $k_0$ such that $\sum_{k>k_0}|y (k)|^2 +\left (\sum_{k>k_0}|y (k)|^2\right)^{1/2}<\varepsilon/2$ and $|x_n (i)-y (i)|<\varepsilon /2^i $ for $i=1,\ldots,n_0$ and $n>k_0$.

Then  \begin{align}|\langle x_n,y\rangle -1|&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}(x_n (k)-y (k))\,\overline {y (k)}+\sum_{k>k_0}^\infty x_n (k)\,\overline {y (k)}+|y (k)|^2\,\right|\\ \ \\ &\leq\frac\varepsilon 2+\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\frac\varepsilon  {2^{k}}<\varepsilon. 
\end{align}

Going back to $(1) $, if $n>k_0$,$$\|x_n-y\|^2\leq2-2\text {Re}\,\langle x_n,y\rangle=2\text {Re}\, (1-\langle x_n,y\rangle )<2\varepsilon. 
$$

Comment: If the OP is familiar with weak$*$-convergence, it's enlightening to prove that weak$*$-convergence in $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ is equivalent to pointwise convergence.  Then $\langle x_{n}, y \rangle \to \langle y, y \rangle = \|y\|^{2}$ follows without recourse to the $\delta-\epsilon$ proof above.

Comment: @martin-argerami, Thanks for your response. As far as I know $\langle x_n,y \rangle= \sum_k x(k) \overline{y(k)}$, so when you expanded $|1-\langle x_n,y \rangle|$, what happened to $\sum_{k>n_0} |x_n(k)||y(k)|$?

Comment: Yes, that term was missing; one deals with it via Cauchy-Schwarz.  It should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_n(i)\to y(i)$ for all $i$, Fatou's lemma implies that
$$ 1=||y||_2^2=\sum_i|y(i)|^2\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_i|x_n(i)|^2=\liminf_{n\to\infty}||x_n||_2^2 $$

On the other hand, since all the $x_n$ are in the unit ball, we have
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}||x_n||_2^2\leq 1$$
and combining the two inequalities above shows that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}||x_n||_2=1$$

Next, observe that
$$ 2|y|^2+2|x_n|^2-|x_n-y|^2\geq 0$$ 
so Fatou's lemma implies that
$$ 4\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_i[2|y(i)|^2+2|x_n(i)|^2-|x_n(i)-y(i)|^2] $$
$$ =4-\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_i|x_n-y|^2$$
and rearranging shows that
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_i|x_n(i)-y(i)|^2=0$$
which is the desired result.